# Android Fragment show() not always working

Tags: android, android-fragments, show-hide

I have few fragments. I have to swap them very often - so I dont want to use `replace` method. I'm using `show` and `hide` instead. Its working but rarely it doesn't show any fragment...

```
    if (fragment.isHidden()) {
        hideAll();
        FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.show(fragment);
        ft.commit();
        Log.i(TAG, "swaped to fragment: " + fragment.toString());
    }
    else
        Log.i(TAG, "fragment already visible");
```

This code is working in most cases but few times it leaves blank spot (only `hideAll` is working)

Do you know what (and why) it is happening?